# Capture X11/GTK+ keyboard shortcut events - change desktop/workspace

Tags: linux, events, gtk, x11

In Linux (most distros?) there is a Keyboard Shortcuts settings app that lets you set keyboard shortcuts like the key combination that minimizes a window or switches to the next workspace/desktop or moves to the next media track.  I want to connect to the event that is fired when the defined shortcut is pressed rather than the key combination as the key combination can change but the event is always the event.  Specifically I want to capture the next/previous workspace/desktop events, not the workspace/desktop changing, but the keyboard request to make the change.

However, I cannot figure out where these events are surfaced.  Does anyone know where I might connect to these events?  I would think GTK+ has some way to surface it, but even if I have to go down to X11/XLib, I'm ok with that.

Ultimately I will code this in python, but for now I'm just looking for a way to capture these events.